# get/use radio button value android

Tags: java, android, radio-button

**I FIGURED OUT WHAT I WAS DOING. I HAD THE VARIABLE NAME IN QUOTES WITH THE REST OF THE URL STRING.**

How do you save the value of a Radio button into a variable and use that variable later.

I can see the variable `Day_Item` in my LogCat and the value is in there but when  try using Day_Item later it does not show the valuable.

Below is a section of my code that shows the buttons.

```
String Day_Item = null;
    public class SearchDB extends Activity {
        private static final String TAG = "MyApp";
        String start_log = "STARTED";
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);


        final RadioButton radio_monday = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.monday);
        radio_monday.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
cityspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) 
     {
      int id = parent.getId();

       if (spinner2_count2 < spinner2_count1 ) {
           spinner2_count2++;  } 
          else 
          {
                 String city_spinner_log = "CITY SPINNER";
                 Log.d(TAG, city_spinner_log);

                    String item = cityspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String nameContentType = "name";
                    String cityURL = "GetRestaurant.php?day=Day_Item&city=" + item;
                    Log.d(TAG, cityURL);
                    String shop_data =  DataCall.getJSON(cityURL,nameContentType);
                    Log.d(TAG,  shop_data);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("shopData", shop_data);

                       Intent myIntent = new Intent(SearchDB.this, ShowRestaurant.class);
                       myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                       startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
           }


    }
      }

   //ONCLICKLISTENER that saves RADIO value into a variable.

    public OnClickListener radio_listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on clicks

            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
            Day_Item = (String) rb.getText();
            Log.d(TAG,Day_Item);
            Toast.makeText(SearchDB.this, Day_Item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: what does "later" means for you? (Swicthing activity eg?)

Comment: same activity. so the user has to select a radio option first that variable is later used in the same activity after they have selected a spinner option. Both variable are then used in a URL. But when I logcat the url string instead of the value in the variable it just says the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a bit more code to get a good solid answer. Such as how is Day_Item allocated? And is it's scope global? Are you calling it from another activity or the one it's allocated within? These are just guesses at this point:

1) Are you sure your onClickListener isn't firing multiple times? Thus setting Day_Item to an undesired text or nothing at all?

2) Rather a question/answer,

> "but when try using Day_Item later it does not show the valuable"

I'm assuming this means that it is null? Well if it's being set properly, and then it is being null'd... it either is being explicitly null'd by you somewhere (such as (1)) or else the allocation and scope are the issue area I believe...

Comment: I am updated my code above. the variable will be read in the same activity. so the user has to select a radio option first that variable is later used in the same activity after they have selected a spinner option. Both variable are then used in a URL. But when I logcat the url string instead of the value in the variable it just says the variable name.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks your feedback actually made me go back through my code and I found my mistake. Checked!